# Accessing JSON encoded MuliDimensional array using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have an multidimensional array

```
$array = array(
    "Level1"=>array(
        "Level11"=>array(
            "level111"=>'value1',
            "level112"=>'value2',
            ),
        "Level12"=>array(
            "level121"=>'value1',
            "level122"=>'value2',
            ),
        ),
    "Level2"=>array(
        "Level21"=>array(
            "level211"=>'value1',
            "level212"=>'value2',
            ),
        "Level22"=>array(
            "level221"=>'value1',
            "level222"=>'value2',
            ),
        )
    );
echo json_encode($array);
```

This encoded JSON is sent after receiving AJAX POST request using jQuery.

```
$.post(
    'mypage.php',
    {
        param1: value1,
        param2: value2
    },
    function(data) {
        //Now I can access the 1st level JSON value easily like
        alert(data.Level1); 

        // But

        // I am trying to access the values like 

        alert(data.Level1.Level11.level112); //which is not possible
    },
    "json"
);
```

If you have understood my question, do you know how I could tackle this problem.

Comment: Why is `data.level1.level11.level112` not possible?

Comment: Have you checked what string is generated by `json_encode()`? Btw even `data.level1` should not work, because the key is named `Level1` (capital L).

Comment: @Pekka, I dont know, that code was supposed to work, but it didn't. @Felix Kling, Yes it can be accesed as array,  like `dt = data.level1; i = dt['level11'][level112]` and I just created a sample of my code, I will correct it right away, I have 3 more levels in my actual code.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/KjHJd/ (JSON generated by http://codepad.org/jUiDCeq6), the error must be somewhere else. You should get *some* error message on the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, my guess: You use capital letters in some of your keys in PHP but not in JS. Your line should be:

```
data.Level1.Level11.level112
```

Note that it is *Level1* with captial *L*, not *level1*.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KjHJd/)

Comment: @Starx: Well, then you should provide a better example. As you can see in the demo, this would be what `json_encode` generates. And it is accessible.

Comment: I am a bit confused now, It wasn't working in my case, That means there must be another point I am missing. I will check it out. Tnx, for showing me the demo.

Comment: Are you sure the encoded JSON from PHP, is exactly like that in you fiddle?

Comment: @Starx: I copy and pasted it from http://codepad.org/jUiDCeq6. But nevertheless, make sure that your server is generating the right JSON.